# Убрать все символы, кроме " a-z A-Z . ' - " - PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите регулярное выражение. Необходимо удалить все символы, кроме:

```
a-z
A-Z
.
'
-
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$str = "AaBb ..'. - русский текст, 123456";
$str = preg_replace("/[^a-z'-.]/i", '', $str);
echo $str;
```

Вывод:

> AaBb..'.-

Если нужны будут пробелы, добавьте пробел в скобки.

Comment: `Если нужны будут пробелы, добавьте \s в скобки.` - вредный совет для ПРОБЕЛОВ.

Comment: @Visman, причина вреда?

Comment: Прочитайте, что входит в пробельные символы `\s`.

Comment: @Visman, соглашусь, для пробела, лучше использовать пробел. - Исправил ответ.